# data duplication while extracting data from a site

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, webdriver

I am trying to extract every company name, website, phone, email and save that data into an excel file, the name of the company gets extracted correctly, the problem is that not every company has a website or phone or an email so this code just duplicates the first phone that it finds to all the other companies.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import pandas as pd
import time
from openpyxl import Workbook

url = "https://www.dmcc.ae/business-search?directory=1&submissionGuid=2c8df029-a92e-4b5d-a014-7ef9948e664b"
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get(url)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 50)

wait.until(
    EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#hs-eu-confirmation-button"))
).click()
wait.until(
    EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#pym-0 > iframe"))
)
list = wait.until(
    EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "searched-list "))
)
button = wait.until(
    EC.element_to_be_clickable(
        (By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a[ng-click='setPage(pager.currentPage + 1)']")
    )
)


comp_list=[]
# while (
#     # Last Page has disabled the li element
#     not "disabled"
#     in driver.find_element_by_css_selector(
#         "li[ng-class='{disabled:pager.currentPage === pager.totalPages}']"
#     )
#     .get_attribute("class")
#     .split()
# ):
for i in range(10):
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", button)

    for e in list:
        name = e.find_element_by_tag_name("h4").text
        website = e.find_element_by_xpath("//a[contains(@class, 'website')]").text
        phone = e.find_element_by_xpath("//a[contains(@class, 'telephone')]").text
        email = e.find_element_by_xpath("//a[contains(@class, 'emailid')]").text
        comp = {
                'name': name,
                'website': website,
                'phone': phone,
                'email': email
                }   
        comp_list.append(comp)

    wait.until(EC.invisibility_of_element((By.CLASS_NAME,"sfloadingBackground")))
    button.click()
    list = wait.until(
        EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "searched-list "))
    )
    

print(comp_list)
df = pd.DataFrame(comp_list) 
print(df)
df.to_excel('comp.xlsx',index=False)
driver.quit()
```

the code below is the part of the code that extracts the data(name, website, phone, email)

```
for e in list:
        name = e.find_element_by_tag_name("h4").text
        website = e.find_element_by_xpath("//a[contains(@class, 'website')]").text
        phone = e.find_element_by_xpath("//a[contains(@class, 'telephone')]").text
        email = e.find_element_by_xpath("//a[contains(@class, 'emailid')]").text
```

note: the outer loop just changes the pages and every page has 10 companies.

Comment: If your xpathing from an element use .// .

Comment: use relative xpath with `dot` as first char `.//a[...]`. If you use `//` then it starts searching from the begining of file.

Comment: The next issue is just using a try except to set the value instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make the try and except into a method and so forth but this sets everything correctly. I'd also suggest naming list something else due to it being a keyword but it's up to you. Sometimes website is blank so you can make default value blank if you want instead of None so far.

```
for i in range(10):
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", button)

    for e in list:
        name = e.find_element_by_tag_name("h4").text
        try:
            website = e.find_element_by_xpath(".//a[contains(@class, 'website')]").text
        except:
            website = "None"
        try:
            phone = e.find_element_by_xpath(".//a[contains(@class, 'telephone')]").text
        except:
            phone = "None"
        try:
            email = e.find_element_by_xpath(".//a[contains(@class, 'emailid')]").text
        except:
            email = "None"
        comp = {
                'name': name,
                'website': website,
                'phone': phone,
                'email': email
                }   
        comp_list.append(comp)

    wait.until(EC.invisibility_of_element((By.CLASS_NAME,"sfloadingBackground")))
    button.click()
    list = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "searched-list ")))
    

print(comp_list)
df = pd.DataFrame(comp_list) 
print(df)
```

Outputs

```
[{'name': '1 BOXOFFICE DMCC', 'website': 'None', 'phone': 'None', 'email': 'None'}, {'name': '1 INTERNATIONAL FINCENTRE ASSOCIATES DMCC', 'website': 'None', 'phone': 'None', 'email': 'None'}, {'name': '1000HEADS CONSULTING DMCC', 'website': 'None', 'phone': 'None', 'email': 'None'}, {'name': '108 CONSULTING DMCC', 'website': '', 'phone': '+97145845300', 'email': 'avinash@108dmcc.com'}, {'name': '1291 GROUP DMCC', 'website': 'None', 'phone': 'None', 'email': 'None'}, {'name': '12D MODEL DMCC', 'website': '', 'phone': '+97144295866', 'email': 'admin@gcsolutionsltd.co.uk'}, {'name': '168 ASSET MANAGEMENT SFO DMCC', 'website': 'None', 'phone': 'None', 'email': 'None'}, {'name': '19 FAMILY & BUSINESS DMCC', 'website': '', 'phone': '+971562160241', 'email': 'l.olivari@gmail.com'}, {'name': '1DIGI INVESTMENT MANAGEMENT DMCC', 'website': 'None', 'phone': 'None', 'email': 'None'}, {'name': '1ENERGIN DMCC', 'website': 'None', 'phone': 'None', 'email': 'None'}, {'name': '1F SOFT DMCC', 'website': '', 'phone': '+971555563077', 'email': 'mohamed@globallink.ae'}, {'name': '1GP HOLDINGS PTY. LTD. (DMCC BRANCH)', 'website': 'None', 'phone': 'None', 'email': 'None'}, {'name': '1ST CLASS D SFO DMCC', 'website': 'None', 'phone': 'None', 'email': 'None'}, {'name': '21ST CENTURY GROUP HOLDINGS LIMITED (BRANCH)', 'website': 'None', 'phone': 'None', 'email': 'None'}, {'name': '22 MARITIME DMCC', 'website': 'None', 'phone': 'None', 'email': 'None'}, {'name': '237 COMMUNICATIONS DMCC', 'website': 'None', 'phone': 'None', 'email': 'None'}, {'name': '24TTL DIGITAL MARKETING SOLUTIONS DMCC', 'website': 'None', 'phone': 'None', 'email': 'None'}, {'name': '25TH PARALLEL SERVICES DMCC', 'website': 'None', 'phone': 'None', 'email': 'None'}, {'name': '271 CONTAINERS DMCC', 'website': 'None', 'phone': 'None', 'email': 'None'}, {'name': '2A IT SERVICES DMCC', 'website': 'None', 'phone': 'None', 'email': 'None'}, {'name': '2BEROSE DMCC', 'website': 'None', 'phone': 'None', 'email': 'None'}, {'name': '2DFINE SERVICES DMCC', 'website': 'None', 'phone': 'None', 'email': 'None'}, {'name': '2E INTERNATIONAL DMCC', 'website': 'None', 'phone': 'None', 'email': 'None'}, {'name': '2G GLOBAL MARKETS DMCC', 'website': 'None', 'phone': 'None', 'email': 'None'}, {'name': '2ID GROUP DMCC', 'website': 'www.2id-events.com', 'phone': '+971502377872', 'email': 'alia@2id-events.com'}, {'name': '2M KABLO DMCC', 'website': 'www.2mkablo.com', 'phone': '+971501643353', 'email': 'iccetin@2mkablo.com'}, {'name': '3 X DIAMONDS DMCC', 'website': '3xdiamondsdmcc.com', 'phone': '+97144341915', 'email': '3xdiamondsdmcc@gmail.com'}, {'name': '321 EVENTS DMCC', 'website': 'None', 'phone': 'None', 'email': 'None'}, {'name': '333 TRADING DMCC', 'website': 'DEC TOWERS # 2 APARTMEN # 2306, dUBAI MARINA', 'phone': '+97143637752', 'email': 'afattah@333tradingjlt.ae'}, {'name': '33VOICES IQ DMCC', 'website': 'None', 'phone': 'None', 'email': 'None'}, {'name': '360 COMPRESSION SERVICES DMCC', 'website': 'None', 'phone': 'None', 'email': 'None'}, {'name': '360 DECORO DMCC', 'website': 'www.360decoro.com', 'phone': '+971563531005', 'email': 'dubai@360decoro.com'}, {'name': '360 EXPANSION CONSULTING DMCC', 'website': '', 'phone': '+97143698916', 'email': 'office@360exco.com'}, {'name': '3A COMPOSITES MIDDLE EAST (BRANCH)', 'website': 'None', 'phone': 'None', 'email': 'None'}, {'name': '3B TRADING DMCC', 'website': '', 'phone': '+97144328300', 'email': 'khaled.bassatne@bbenergy.com'}, {'name': '3BFAB 3D PRINTING SOLUTIONS DMCC', 'website': '', 'phone': '+97142443135', 'email': 'info@3bfab-dmcc.ae'}, {'name': '3CORE DMCC', 'website': '', 'phone': '+971505583613', 'email': 'info@3core-os.com'}, {'name': '3CUBE TECHMED DMCC', 'website': 'None', 'phone': 'None', 'email': 'None'}, {'name': '3CX SOFTWARE DMCC', 'website': 'None', 'phone': 'None', 'email': 'None'}, {'name': '3D METAL TRADING DMCC', 'website': '', 'phone': '+97142955727', 'email': 'cs@m-hq.com'}, {'name': '3EX DIAM ME DMCC', 'website': 'None', 'phone': 'None', 'email': 'None'}, {'name': '3F MUSIC DMCC', 'website': '', 'phone': '+971555555553', 'email': 'fardinfard@gmail.com'}, {'name': '3FIVE8 TECHNOLOGIES DMCC', 'website': 'None', 'phone': 'None', 'email': 'None'}, {'name': '3Y AGRICULTURE RESEARCH AND CONSULTANCY DMCC', 'website': 'None', 'phone': 'None', 'email': 'None'}, {'name': '4 SPACE MANAGEMENT DMCC', 'website': 'www.4space.ae', 'phone': '+97144385537', 'email': 'firas@4space.ae'}, {'name': '4 WALLS ART GALLERY DMCC', 'website': 'None', 'phone': 'None', 'email': 'None'}, {'name': '42 INTERNATIONAL DMCC', 'website': 'None', 'phone': 'None', 'email': 'None'}, {'name': '4E CONSULTANCY AND CONSTRUCTION SERVICES DMCC', 'website': '', 'phone': '+971503034051', 'email': 'operations@tamimiconsultancy.com'}, {'name': '4PM CONSULTING DMCC', 'website': 'None', 'phone': 'None', 'email': 'None'}, {'name': '4S DENTAL LABORATORY DMCC', 'website': '', 'phone': '+97144562950', 'email': 'dentallab4s@outlook.com'}, {'name': '4SIGHT BUSINESS CONSULTING DMCC', 'website': 'None', 'phone': 'None', 'email': 'None'}, {'name': '4SIGHT DRIVE DMCC', 'website': 'https://4sightglobal.com/', 'phone': '+97144548601', 'email': 'dinesh@4sight-global.com'}, {'name': '4SIGHT PLUS DMCC', 'website': 'https://4sightglobal.com/', 'phone': '+971505785140', 'email': 'anjan@4sight-global.com'}, {'name': '4SIGHT RESEARCH & ANALYTICS DMCC', 'website': 'https://4sightglobal.com/', 'phone': '+97144548601', 'email': 'mahesh@4sight-global.com'}, {'name': '4T COMMODITIES & EMERGING MARKETS DMCC', 'website': 'None', 'phone': 'None', 'email': 'None'}, {'name': '50 NORTH AGRO DMCC', 'website': 'None', 'phone': 'None', 'email': 'None'}, {'name': '51 PEG TECHNOLOGIES DMCC', 'website': 'None', 'phone': 'None', 'email': 'None'}, {'name': '5TH CONSULTING DMCC', 'website': 'www.5th.ae', 'phone': '+97142778085', 'email': 'v.alarde@5th.ae'}, {'name': '6 SEGMENTS SERVICES DMCC', 'website': 'None', 'phone': 'None', 'email': 'None'}, {'name': '609 EXPERIENCE DMCC', 'website': 'None', 'phone': 'None', 'email': 'None'}, {'name': '7 BROS DMCC', 'website': '', 'phone': '+97144458378', 'email': '7brosdmcc@gmail.com'}, {'name': '73 CO DMCC', 'website': 'None', 'phone': 'None', 'email': 'None'}, {'name': '748 AIR SERVICES DMCC', 'website': '', 'phone': '+971528109736', 'email': 'arjexports@arj.ca'}, {'name': '777 DIAMOND DMCC', 'website': 'None', 'phone': 'None', 'email': 'None'}, {'name': '777 RENT A CAR DMCC', 'website': '20:00', 'phone': '+971509729407', 'email': 'afkar_hassan2010@hotmail.com'}, {'name': '79TH GRP DMCC', 'website': 'None', 'phone': 'None', 'email': 'None'}, {'name': '7CLICK NETWORK DMCC', 'website': 'None', 'phone': 'None', 'email': 'None'}, {'name': '7HEAVEN TECHNOLOGY DMCC', 'website': 'www.7heaventech.com', 'phone': '+971 55 9478601', 'email': 'imran.s@7heaventech.com'}, {'name': '7PQRS DMCC', 'website': '', 'phone': '+971588631656', 'email': 'tigas.catherine@ymail.com'}, {'name': '7TH FLOOR CONSULTING DMCC', 'website': 'None', 'phone': 'None', 'email': 'None'}, {'name': '7TICKETS DMCC', 'website': '', 'phone': '+971501002473', 'email': 'feras@7tickets.com'}, {'name': '8 POINT MEDIA DMCC', 'website': '', 'phone': '+97143998158', 'email': 'sam@8pointmedia.com'}, {'name': '800 MEAT DMCC', 'website': '', 'phone': '+971506400204', 'email': 'fb-800meat@hotmail.com'}, {'name': '800DOCTOR DMCC', 'website': 'None', 'phone': 'None', 'email': 'None'}, {'name': '800TICKETS DMCC', 'website': '', 'phone': '+9718008425387', 'email': 'legal@itp.com'}, {'name': '818 VAULT DMCC', 'website': 'www.818vault.com', 'phone': '+971504581809', 'email': 'vik@818vault.com'}, {'name': '89 TECHNO CONSULTING COMPANY DMCC', 'website': 'None', 'phone': 'None', 'email': 'None'}, {'name': '8LABS GROUP COMMERCIAL BROKERS DMCC', 'website': 'None', 'phone': 'None', 'email': 'None'}, {'name': '8LANG DMCC', 'website': 'None', 'phone': 'None', 'email': 'None'}, {'name': 'A & A AVIATION TRADING DMCC', 'website': 'None', 'phone': 'None', 'email': 'None'}, {'name': 'A & A EXCELLENCE TRADING DMCC', 'website': '', 'phone': '+971559386418', 'email': 'said@asaworldwide.net'}, {'name': 'A & A SYNERGY DMCC', 'website': '', 'phone': '+971567560353', 'email': 'ajayhalwasiya@gmail.com'}, {'name': 'A & A TECHNOLOGIES DMCC', 'website': 'www.aatechnologies.net', 'phone': '+97144412268', 'email': 'faisal@aatechnologies.net'}, {'name': 'A & D INTERNATIONAL TRADING DMCC', 'website': '', 'phone': '+971507285246', 'email': 'andrea@and-dmcc.com'}, {'name': 'A 1 CONSULTANCY SERVICES DMCC', 'website': 'www.aone-consultancy.com', 'phone': '+971528869360', 'email': 'a1.jlt.dubai@gmail.com'}, {'name': 'A AND J DMCC', 'website': 'None', 'phone': 'None', 'email': 'None'}, {'name': 'A CEUTICALS DMCC', 'website': 'None', 'phone': 'None', 'email': 'None'}, {'name': 'A CONSULT DMCC', 'website': 'None', 'phone': 'None', 'email': 'None'}, {'name': 'A DIGITAL COM DMCC', 'website': 'None', 'phone': 'None', 'email': 'None'}, {'name': 'A G STAR DMCC', 'website': 'None', 'phone': 'None', 'email': 'None'}, {'name': 'A GEM STAR DMCC', 'website': '.', 'phone': '+97144219251', 'email': 'agemstardmcc@gmail.com'}, {'name': 'A K A EXPORTS DMCC', 'website': 'None', 'phone': 'None', 'email': 'None'}, {'name': 'A K DIGITAL CONSULTING MEA DMCC', 'website': 'None', 'phone': 'None', 'email': 'None'}, {'name': 'A K T MARITIME DMCC', 'website': 'None', 'phone': 'None', 'email': 'None'}, {'name': 'A M K BROKERS DMCC', 'website': 'None', 'phone': 'None', 'email': 'None'}, {'name': 'A ONE DIAM DMCC', 'website': 'None', 'phone': 'None', 'email': 'None'}, {'name': 'A R HOURIE ENTERPRISES GULF DMCC', 'website': 'www.hourie.com', 'phone': '+971585898079', 'email': 'gmouawad@hourie.com'}, {'name': 'A R IMPEX DMCC', 'website': '', 'phone': '+971558794024', 'email': 'arimpexdmcc@hotmail.com'}, {'name': 'A R J TRADING DMCC', 'website': 'None', 'phone': 'None', 'email': 'None'}, {'name': 'A SWEET SPOT DMCC', 'website': 'www.asweetspotevents.com', 'phone': '+971552388726', 'email': 'linaelfassi@asweetspotevents.com'}]
```